# Django - Prevent date range overlapping

Tags: django, date, django-models, date-range

```
class Session(models.Model):
  tutor = models.ForeignKey(User)
  start_time = models.DateTimeField()
  end_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

What is the best way to always prevent `start_time` from overlapping `end_time` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should do this at the form level, see [Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) for instructions on how to do this, it would look like this:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(YourForm, self).clean()
    if cleaned_data['start_time'] > cleaned_data['end_time']:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_(u'Start time must be before end time'))
```

Also, you can enforce it at low level in the save method or in a [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save) [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/):

```
from django.db.models import signals

class StartTimeAfterEndTimeException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(StartTimeAfterEndTimeException, self).__init__(
            'Start time %s should not be after end time %s' % (
                model.start_time, model.end_time))

def session_force_end_time(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.start_time >= instance.end_time:
        raise StartTimeAfterEndTimeException(instance)
signals.pre_save.connect(session_force_end_time, sender=Session)
```

But that's pretty low level so it's not user friendly.

Comment: At form level, I have to define this behavior for each form of my applications right ?

Comment: You should define this behavior once and only once. You could define this behavior in SessionForm, and have other form classes for Session to inherit from SessionForm.

Comment: Ok I see, I'll try to inherit forms. Thank you